# Create method in cakePHP not working

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm coding a site with cakePHP.  I'm writing an "add" function in VideosControllers:

```
    public function admin_add(){

    $this->Video->create();

    $this->Video->save(array(
        'name' => 'New video'
    ));

    return $this->redirect(array(
            'controller' => 'Videos',
            'action' => 'admin_edit',
            $this->Video->id
        ), 301);
}
```

There is no View for this function.

When I call this function admin_add, I'm redirected to an admin_edit page but the function doesn't create any video in the database and the admin_edit.

I tried to put a die() just before the return, but the the user is redirected anyway, which is strange.

Comment: Does enabling debug mode return anything? What query's are executed?

Comment: It sounds like you may not even be hitting the `admin_add` action if `die()` doesn't do anything.

Comment: Actually debug mode is already enabled. And even if I change the code to display the queries, the same redirection is still executed. The code is:

public function admin_add(){
  debug($this->Video);
  $this->Video->create();
  $this->Video->save(array(
   'name' => 'New video'
  ));
$log = $this->Video->getDataSource()->getLog(false, false);
  debug($log);

return $this->redirect(array(
    'controller' => 'Videos',
    'action' => 'admin_edit',
    $this->Video->id
   ), 301);
 }

Comment: @FabienTrestour unless you put a `die` before the `redirect` you won't see the response from your `debug`s. You could always use `$this->log($log)` instead to write to the error logs. You can then view the error log after the redirect.

Comment: @drmonkeyninja : I agree with you. I called the function http://localhost/cakephp/admin/Videos/add so admin_add should be called...

Comment: Here is the content of the log file:
2015-09-17 15:38:18 Error: [MissingControllerException] Controller class JsController could not be found.
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\cakephp\app\webroot\index.php(92): Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(CakeRequest), Object(CakeResponse))
#1 {main}

Comment: Your log error indicates something is trying to go to localhost/cakephp/js or more likely localhost/cakephp/admin/js. This could mean you have a link or a route reference somewhere that is not saying admin=false. You could also wrap $this->Video->save() in a try/catch (\Exception $e) { die($e->getMessage()); } to see if the save is throwing an error.

Comment: There is no error thrown when saving. But actually, in the database, the video is not even created as I said in my first comment. It's just editing the same video again and again

Comment: Try $this->Video->save($data['Video']['name'] = 'New video');

Comment: @FabienTrestour Your last comment (that it is editing the same video again) provided the clue. The save() is not constructed correctly.

Comment: You should remove the redirect, and look at/show the sql log. Note it's a *bad idea* to do anything via a get request - get requests are supposed to do nothing. It sounds like your db table doesn't have an autoincrement id, you need to show enough details for someone else to be able to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3):

The save() is not coded correctly. You need this:

```
$this->Video->save(array($this->Video->alias => array('name' => 'New Video')));
```

or you could hard-code the alias:

```
$this->Video->save(array('Video' => array('name' => 'New Video')));
```

**EDIT**

My answer here does match [the CakePHP 2.x book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html). However, I am mistaken. There is a variant not mentioned in that book which allows for leaving out the Model name as the array key. If you're interested, follow `Model::save()` through to `Model::set()` in your version of the Cake core files.

I looked at the core files for CakePHP 2.6 and found it's capable of doing quite a bit under the covers with that first save() argument. Those variants are covered by unit tests so they likely will remain available in CakePHP 2.x.

Comment: Not true, the model key is not strictly necessary the code [handles the presense/absense of that optional key automatically](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.0.0/lib/Cake/Model/Model.php#L1068-L1077).

Comment: @AD7six Interesting! That contradicts the CakePHP 2.x documentation, but I checked a recent 2.x release and it sure does seem to still be as you say.

Comment: I refer to the 2.x book / model / saving your data. Example uses alias. You taught me an undocumented feature. The 2.6 code is refactored and does more but your statement remains true. I would delete my answer but our comments may help others.

Comment: A much better answer now.  Understandable to read that page as "it has to be like this" - I don't think a doc change is necessary as it's often better to document/show one way to do something, it's less confusing/ambiguous to readers. That said it's not strictly accurate to say "undocumented" - that means to me entirely unexpected, and the type of behavior you can't rely upon. [There are (a lot of) tests using that data format](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.8/lib/Cake/Test/Case/Model/ModelWriteTest.php#L264), it _is_ an expected way for things to work. anyway +1.

Comment: @AD7six I edited to encompass your further comments.